# Shared folders in the root of a Solution

Tags: asp.net

I have 3 web application in a solution in VS2010. They use the same CSS, images etc. How can I make a shared folder in the solution's root to access from all web app? So for example I want a "CSS" folder in the root to store the CSS files, and access them from all web application.
Thanks

Structure:

Solution
 - Project1
 - Project2
 - Project3
 - Images 
 - CSS

I want to store css files and images in a central place (at the root folder of the solution), but not inside any of the projects.

Comment: deploy these folders as seperate web app say like `media.yourcompany.com`

Comment: What do you mean? You want to access them from VS2010? or when they are up as a web site? do you want to store your CSS files in one place and add them to 3 projects? or you just want to use them in 3 web sites?

Answer (score 0):

As Furqan said, deploy those common elements as their own web application on the server.  Then refer to the elements using the full url, such as media.yourcompany.com/css/site.css